# I want to write a custom directive for ui-grid with different input columnDefs

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope, angular-ui-grid

This is my Controller

```
$scope.usersList = {};

$scope.usersList = {
    paginationPageSizes: [10,15, 20],
    paginationPageSize: 10,
    columnDefs: [
        { name: 'userId', cellTemplate: '<div class="ui-grid-cell-contents"><a ui-sref="appSetting.userSelected({userId: row.entity.userId})">{{ row.entity.userId }}</a></div>' },
        { name: 'firstName' },
        { name: 'lastName' },
        { name: 'emailId' },
        {
            name: 'action',
            cellTemplate: '<div>' +
                    '  <button  ng-click="grid.appScope.sampledetails()">Delete</button>' +
                    '</div>',
            enableSorting: false,
            enableColumnMenu: false
        }
    ]
};
```

and this is my .cshtml

```
<div id="grid1" ui-grid="gridOptions" class="grid"></div>
```

I want to write this in such a way that it should be used in other .cshmtls, but the columnDefs varies depending on table column name. How should I write in such a way that ths user should give the columnsDefs in directive along with pagination?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your question is hard to understand, hopefully I got it right. You want to define default-settings for your grid but enable the user to input some special settings if needed?

Warp ui-grid in your own directive. Pass your wanted arguments into that directive and create default settings in your directive.

Your .cshtml. You pass your settings variable into that.

```
<my-grid options="usersList" />
```

Your Directive. Grab the settings there (see options: '=') and bind that to controller or scope.

```
angular.module('app').directive('myGrid', myGrid);
function myGrid() {
  return {
    templateUrl : 'grid.html',
    controller : 'GridCtrl',
    controllerAs : 'grid',
    restrict: 'E',
    scope: {
      options : '=',
    },
    bindToController: true,
  };
}
```

Your Controller. Now you can access your settings in that controller.
There you could combine the default settings with your inserted settings and pass that into the directive template.

```
angular.module('app').controller('GridCtrl', GridCtrl);
function GridCtrl() {
  var grid = this;

  console.log(grid.options); // containts your settings

  grid.gridOptions = {
    paginationPageSize: grid.options.paginationPageSize,
    ...,
    columnDefs: grid.options.columnDefs
    etc
  }
}
```

And your grid.html, you pass the combined settings into the grid-API.

```
<div id="grid1" ui-grid="grid.gridOptions" class="grid"></div>
```

There are many more details to watch out for, but thats a possible setup.

e: I made a [Plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/I03kq05fZx2UkB4USHSZ?p=preview) for another similar question. For future reference.