# using angular factory in multiple controllers

Tags: angular-ui-grid, angularjs-factory

I am using angular ui grid. At first I implemented this in a controller and it works fine after all my customization. As I am using multiple grids I cannot write a long controller each time. So, I converted it to factory. I kept the common function in factory and column definition and data in controller. Now when I use this factory in more than 1 controllers, the last controller is overriding all others. 
1) Is it correct to make this grid in a factory?
2) If yes how do I overcome this problem?
3) By using factory for this grid, my gridObj.gridApi.pagination.on is throwing error(gridObj is the singleton object that I am returning).

Any suggestion is welcome. Thanks a lot in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You should use a Directive instead. Factories create a single Instant (see [Angular Provider Documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/providers) and wont create a private scope, which you need to not override your data.

> Note: All services in Angular are singletons.

But Directives provide a private scope and create new instances every time they are called in HTML if you want them to.

```
//directive
scope: { // this option creates isolated scopes
  something : '=',
},
```

I created a [Plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/I03kq05fZx2UkB4USHSZ?p=preview) showcasing a possible setup. For some more written details please see my [answer from few days ago](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32478669/4299313).

Your HTML might look like this afterwards

```
<my-grid options="all.firstOptions" class="grid"></my-grid>
```

Where `my-grid` is your directive and `options=""` are your special settings (and whatever else you wish to use in the directive). In your directive you declare the default settings and merge them with the special ones.

```
scope.gridOptions = {
          data: scope.options.data, //private scoped from options : '=',
          columnDefs: scope.options.colDef || defaultColDef, // optional setting or default setting
          // ... some more default data
        };
```

If you have any specific questions, let me know.

Comment: Thank you for answering my question but it didn't solve my problem. I have one directive as well to load grid template. I already mentioned that each grid will have its own columns and data, rest of the functionality remain same. Anything needed for any use case then the developer will write their own functionality in the controller. What should be the approach for this?

Comment: Sorry, I dont understand your question. Using a Factory as stated in your question doesnt work, you need a directive instead. And if you want to create different Grids (data, columns, etc)  with the same base configuration, you can use my approach. Please try to be more specific about your needs.

Comment: I have added my example in http://plnkr.co/edit/FuwHnrUjCBJ0BgQ2UM5k?p=preview. The second grid header is overwritten to first grid header. if you uncomment the code for gridApi.pagination then it throws error. Please have a look on this and help me. Thanks.

Comment: `scope:false` is your problem, you need a private Scope. Otherwise your data will be overwritten.