# Ui-grid: how can I create multiple ui grids dynamically

Tags: angular-ui-grid

I need to display multiple ui grids in my screen. The number of grids are dynamic.
Scenario: I am adding some people in a list and proceeds to next screen where I need to display their details in a separate ui grid. How can I create grid options dynamically?

Answer (score 0):

Wrap up the code and html inside a directive, pass the table data to the directive.See the answer from user CMR here...I hope this helps.
[Custom directive for Ui Grid](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32470817/i-want-to-write-a-custom-directive-for-ui-grid-with-different-input-columndefs)